# Optimize large MySQL SELECT WHERE IN statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I need to perform a large SELECT WHERE IN query on MySQL and I need it to run quickly. I have a table with more than 100 million rows with the primary key on a varchar 127 (and it has to be that way).

I am performing a SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE col1 IN ($in) where $in has 5000 values. I essentially just need to find which of the 5,000 values are in the table in the primary key col1.

The query takes between 1 and 10 seconds generally but is usually about 7 or 8 seconds.

Is there a more optimal, fast way of performing SELECTS with large IN clauses on huge tables indexed by a varchar?

I am using InnoDB on a dedicated server with PHP and PDO. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried putting the values in the `$IN` variable into a temporary table, with the primary key being the value?  Doing a join to this table might help performance.  Also, how many rows are returned?  If the result set is quite large, then time may be spent in retrieving the data rather than generating the result set.

Comment: Are the values arbitrary?In other words maybe add at the beginning of WHERE AND value<some max value in the IN clause

Comment: Gordon, I have not tried that and would need the steps spelled out for me as I'm relatively new to large mysql tables. Of the 5,000, anywhere between 1,000 and 5,000 are returned generally, it's a pretty large return set.

Comment: Mihai, yes the values are arbitrary and dispersed all over the table.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

I am guessing that you already have an index on `table(col1)`, otherwise the query would probably take longer than 10 seconds.  If this is not true, then add a column.  Better yet, make the column the primary key.

I have a suspicion that the index doesn't fit into memory.  For this, you will need to find a MySQL DBA (which you should have if you have such a large table) or learn about the memory options for MySQL.  An index not fitting into memory would exhibit this type of behavior.

If this is true, then the behavior should be pretty linear.  So, if you have a list of 500 ids, it should take about one second or a bit less.  If you have 50 ids, then a tenth of a second or so.

It is possible that sorting the list of ids would help in this case.  However, that is really just speculation on my part.

Comment: Yes I should have mentioned it is the primary key on the table. I suppose it's possible the index does not fit into memory, is there a way to check if that's the case? Any pointers on where to look to learn about memory options for mysql? And lastly, the IDs in the table are sorted alphabetically but the IN clause is not - is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: @Guy . . . If `col1` is a primary key, then try sorting the ids in the `in` statement.  If MySQL is checking them one-by-one and the index doesn't fit in memory, then this could benefit performance.